# Is there a Way to search several Youtube-Channels in one API-Call

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I'm wondering if there is a way to get the newest Video-Items of several Youtube-Channels?

Youtube killed the Collection-Feature last month and now I'm thinking about writing my own App for organizing my 400+ Youtube-Subscription.

Would be great, if there is a function to search for new Videos on several channels with ONE API-Call. But it seems to me that the youtube.search.list does only suppport searching in one Channel-Id.

Any Ideas?

If there is no way, I'm thinking about using the Youtube-Push-Notifications and caching the Channel-Items in my own DB, but it would be much simpler to have no own Sever running, but only using the Youtube-Api clientside.

Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no API call to search through multiple channels. Your best solution would use [Push notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications) to get latest videos.